# Qt - How to create extra roles for a QDialogButtonBox

Tags: c++, qt, button, user-interface, enums

I apologize in advance for not having more code to show, this is more of a conceptual question. I am working in Qt 4.7 and I have a QDialogButtonBox in my UI to which I need to add several custom buttons*. I set the buttons up like I normally would. For example, if I'm adding a Save button, I would create it like this:

```
QPushButton *myButton = new QPushButton(tr("Save"));
```

Usually I could just add this to my UI as is. However, I've found with the button box, it needs to have a "ButtonRole" attached, which are built-in to Qt. The only role that seems close to matching what I want is "ActionRole", but that's still sort of vague as to it's meaning when looking at it later in the code. I know theoretically any of the roles could be associated with this button, but it seems like really bad practice to me to attach an unrelated-named role like "RejectRole" or "HelpRole" to it just to make it work. My question is, how can I create a new role, something like "SaveRole", that I can use for this button? I tried putting a line like `#define SaveRole (some int value)` in my code and using that since the ButtonRoles are enumerators, but that gave me an error saying it couldn't convert the parameters. I know there's also NRoles in ButtonRole, and it seems like that can probably be used to create new Roles, but I've been searching for about a half hour and am finding it EXTREMELY difficult to find any information on how to use this. If anyone has suggestions it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*For the record, I know how easy it would be to avoid this problem by using QPushButtons individually instead of a QDialogButtonBox, but my project head wants the button box used, so unfortunately I don't have that option.

EDIT: I forgot to mention before but it may be worth bringing up, this button box is pretty large, and all the built-in roles are already in use.

Comment: You'll find your answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274105/qt-how-to-implement-qdialogbuttonbox-with-qsignalmapper-for-non-standard-button

Comment: @fonZ In that answer though, it seems like they are still using ActionRole when adding it to the buttonbox. That's what I want to avoid. I don't want to have to use or alter any of the preset Roles, since they often aren't applicable to the button's function. Also, it's a large box and all the default roles are already used.

Comment: The roles are just enum entries and unless you need 100 different roles, there are enough roles you can use that are already defined. e.g. ApplyRole, ActionRole, AcceptRole,RejectRole,DestructiveRole,HelpRole,YesRole,NoRole,ResetRole ...

Comment: That's sort of my point though: I DO need more roles than there are predefined

Comment: @thnkwthprtls there is nothing wrong with having different buttons defined with the same role. You can have 200 buttons defined with the actionrole, for instance. I don't see what the problem is. I would recommend writing up a small, self-contained, compilable example so we could give more concrete response. Or, if you solved the problem, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @neuronet Thanks for the response, I didn't realize it was ok to use the same role more than once. Honestly, the code that required this was long enough ago that I don't remember exactly what I did, but I'm about 90% sure my project lead couldn't figure it out either so we just ended up using individual QPushButtons instead.