# How to catch information for Qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qlabel

I have created a Qdialog box using the Qt creator designer as shown below:

[image: dialogoverwrite.ui]

When I need to display it, I'm instantiate the class dialogoverwrite (.cpp, .h and .ui)

```
DialogOverwrite *OverwriteDialog = new DialogOverwrite;
OverwriteDialog->exec();
OverwriteOption = OverwriteDialog->result()
```

My issue is that I want to get the QDialogButtonBox result but I do not know how. the current code, returning the result of the OverwriteDialog but it's not returning any QDialogButtonBox::Yes, QDialogButtonBox::YesToAll ...

How to catch the QButtonGroup result and not the QDialog result.

In the same way, If I want to change the label value from "File(s) and/or Folder(s)" to another label, how to access to this QLabel ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you pressed QDialogButton it was emit signal clicked(QAbstractButton*) by catching this signal you can identify which action button pressed.

Please go through following link it would be help you.

[Qt: How to implement QDialogButtonBox with QSignalMapper for non-standard button ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274105/qt-how-to-implement-qdialogbuttonbox-with-qsignalmapper-for-non-standard-button)

Answer (score 0):

Well the standard way to do this is to handle the result by connecting it. So you could do:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(clickedDialogButton(QAbstractButton*)), 
    SLOT(dialogButton(QAbstractButton* aButton)));
```

Next you would create a function in your class called `dialogButton` (for example) and have that handle the result:

```
void MyUI::dialogButton(QAbstractButton* aButton) {
    // Obtain the standard button
    StandardButton button = buttonBox−>standardButton(button);  

    // Switch on the type of button
    switch (button) {
    case QDialogButtonBox::YesToAll:
        // Do the thing you would like to do here
        break;
    // add some more cases?
    }
}
```

You could also check for the signal given by the `QButtonGroup`. Something like: `void QGroupButton::buttonClicked(QAbstractButton* button)` would work in the same way.

Comment: I had to modify the buttonBox line by this one due to build issue QDialogButtonBox::StandardButton button = Ui_DialogOverwrite::buttonBox->QDialogButtonBox::standardButton(aButton);
but I still have an issue at build saying : invalid use of buttonBox

Comment: That is probably because you should store `OverwriteDialog` and use it to obtain the buttonbox, something like: `OverwriteDialog->buttonBox->standardButton(button);`. In the example I provided I assumed you already did this (hence I just gave it a random name `buttonBox`).

Comment: Thanks but buttonBox is not listed as a part of the OverwriteDialog. The .ui is including it but nothing in the class happens

Comment: Instead of `buttonBox` use the name that you have for the group element.